# Repetir linhas anteriores quando não houver registro na data SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Amigos, boa tarde!

Me deparei com um problema no trabalho hoje, e ainda não consegui uma solução para o mesmo. Como não tenho muita experiência na area de banco de dados estou com dificuldade para a resolução deste problema, ficaria muito feliz com uma ajuda, dica etc...

Estou com o seguinte problema: 
tenho uma tabela onde os registros são atualizados diáriamente, mas nem todos os ID possuem registros atualizados diariamente.

Preciso que quando um não haja próxima data repetir a anterior 
exemplo:

[image: Exemplo:]

```
CREATE TABLE #CADASTRO ( ID INT IDENTITY, DATA_ATUALIZACAO DATE, VALOR INT)

INSERT INTO #CADASTRO VALUES ('20170201',1), ('20170204',4), ('20170205',5)

DECLARE @DATAINICIAL DATE = '20170201'; 
DECLARE @DATAFINAL DATE = '20170205';

;

WITH CTE AS 
( 

SELECT 

@DATAINICIAL AS DATA_GUIA 

/**********/UNION ALL/**********/ 

SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATA_GUIA) 
FROM CTE 
WHERE DATA_GUIA < @DATAFINAL


)

SELECT 
    B.DATA_GUIA, 
    A.* 
FROM #CADASTRO AS A
RIGHT JOIN CTE AS B ON A.DATA_ATUALIZACAO = B.DATA_GUIA
```

Comment: coloca a query que está usando e a estrutura das tabelas

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo em questão pra ficar simples.

Comment: Você deve editar a sua pergunta para acrescentar mais informações, não publicar uma resposta para ela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize uma `subquery` combinando `ORDER BY` pela data que deseja e `TOP`:

```
DECLARE @datainicial DATE = '20170201';
DECLARE @datafinal DATE = '20170205';

WITH cte AS (SELECT @datainicial AS data_guia
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, data_guia)
               FROM cte
              WHERE data_guia < @datafinal)
SELECT b.data_guia,
       (SELECT TOP(1) c.valor
          FROM #cadastro c
         WHERE c.data_atualizacao <= b.data_guia
        ORDER BY c.data_atualizacao DESC) AS valor
  FROM cte b;
```

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4220a/3).

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo! exatamente oque preciso.

Answer (score 2):

basta selecionar a maior data, e agrupar pelas outras colunas. Fiz um exemplo:

```
select 
    id,
    max(data_atualizacao) as data_atualizacao,
    valor
from CADASTRO
group by id,valor
order by id
```

e coloquei no SQLFiddle para ver funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db1da/2

Comment: Mas aí é que está. Pro seu exemplo você incluiu 5 registros. Ele quer preencher os "buracos" de tempo ao selecionar os registros. Sendo assim a solução não funcionaria corretamente.

Comment: Entendi quando li sua resposta, havia pensado diferente, mas td certo, vlw +1